# Why doesn't "=" bind my model two-ways?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I understand the "=" in directive parameter to be a two-way model binding.

Yet in this code http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/q2e25nve/12 when I change the value of my model in a function triggered by a button

```
$scope.changeDateTime = function() {
    $scope.date3 = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
};
```

it does not update my control wrapped in my derivative.

**What do I have to do so that my control is updated with the model's date value. I suppose I need another `scope.$apply` but where?**

Comment: *always always always* use objects in `ng-model`. Primitives don't have inheritance. Rule of thumb ... always have a dot in ng-model

Comment: I think you just need that   scope.$watch('date' , function(value, oldvalue) {
             if(value != oldvalue){
              element.data("DateTimePicker").date(scope.date);
             }
        });

Comment: replace with this         element.on('dp.change', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.date = event.date._d;
            });
        }); that's because you are using bootstrap and when you change scope thats doesn't fire change event you just need to watch your scope date in directive hope that's help

Comment: check it here http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedsalah/h2xko3fo/1/

Comment: Great thanks, that works, but to enable the AngularJS variables to continue to update, I had to put the 'dp.change' code, but they seem to work together: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/q2e25nve/14/

Comment: I recomended to use ui.bootstrap.datepicker  directive it's work fine with me here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker